# Node.js/JavaScript wait until required module has completed running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I have an express.js application that uses mongoose to connect with MongoDB. currently, I have the mongoose code to connect with the DB in a separate file since its something used frequently across modules
this the code for the connector

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let host = process.env.DB_HOST;
let port = process.env.DB_PORT;
let name = process.env.DB_NAME;

mongoose
 .connect(`mongodb://${host}:${port}/${name}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
 })
 .then(() => {
     console.log("Connection established with DB");
 })
 .catch(error => {
     console.log(`Error in conecting to database!\n${error}`);
 });
```

I am then requiring this in my main app.js file using

```
require("./database/connector")
```

after that starting the express server with

```
app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log(`server started at port ${PORT}`);})
```

While this runs alright, the output I get is

```
   server started at port 3000
   Connections established with DB
```

Which basically means the database connection happens after the server has been started 
For reasons which I won't dive too deep into right now, I need a way to ensure that the server isn't accepting any requests until the database connection is established (it's not a necessity, but it would make my testing process much easier to deal with, I'm using jest and supertest for testing)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: There has to be more to your code since nobody can use the connected database in what you show.  So, perhaps you need to communicate the database connection itself to other modules, and can then export a promise that resolves to the database connection object itself.  Then, anyone importing can use that promise to both know when it's done connecting and to get the connected database object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Bind the server port listening on the database connection event directly, or return and pass the promise or an event emitter from the database module to the web app module.

```js
mongoose
 .connect(`mongodb://${host}:${port}/${name}`, {
    //...
 })
 .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log(`server started at port ${PORT}`);})
 })
```

2. Add a middleware to your express.js web app, that checks if the database server is connected. (It should be added to the router as the first route.)

```js
var app = express();

// the first route
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // if database connected, continue using following routes
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState == 1) return next();
  // otherwisetell people the server isn't ready.
  res.status(500);
  res.end();
})

// continue what you were doing before
app.use(...)
app.all('/some-path', ...)

app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log(`server started at port ${PORT}`);})
```